# No entiendo exactamente esta función que crea una conexión

Tags: php

Estoy mirando **PHP** y estoy viendo una función de como crear una conexión en **PHP** creo que la **version 7** , corregidme si me equivoco por favor.

Y esta es la **función** que crea la **conexión**:

```
  function connect(){
        try {

            $connection =  "mysql:host=". $this->host .";dbname=". $this->db; 
            $options = [
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE     => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
            ];

            $pdo = new PDO($connection,$this->user,$this->password,$options);

            return $pdo;

        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            //throw $th;
        }
    }
```

A ver la variable `$connection` la entiendo, simplemente concatena las propiedades de la clase para crear la conexión como siempre.
Pero por ejemplo la variable `$options` no se que pretende hacer.
Tampoco la variable `$pdo`.

Y tampoco se porque es la variable `$pdo` la que es retornada en la función.

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar en esta pregunta. Disculpen si no es la forma correcta de pregunta en `StackOverflow` , se que había una etiqueta para este tipo de preguntas, pero no la recuerdo. 
Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La variable `$pdo` guarda al acceso como objeto a la clase PDO mediante una instanción `$objeto = new ClaseNombre()` que es la encargada de que te puedas conectar a MySQL en este caso y es ahí donde pasas a la variable `$connection` que tiene las credenciales de acceso a tu gestor de bases de datos

1. `$pdo` es la que se retorna por que tiene o contiene lo que la conexión por PDO retorna acceso o no acceso
2. `$options` permite almacenar atributos extra de configuración en firma de array asociativo que puedes revisar [aqui](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.setattribute.php)
3. `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` Lanza una excepción generada por PDO cuando se trata la conexión
4. `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` Encargada de habilitar o deshabilitar la simulación de sentencias preparadas (en tu caso se esta mandando como `false`)

En realidad lo que contiene `$connection` y `$options` se pudo haber metido directo en la instancia de PDO que guarda `$pdo` pero lo que hizo el autor fue fragmentar y separar

Comment: De acuerdo, una ultima duda al respecto : que sintaxis tendria la conexion, porque me esta dando un error  y no se si es la sintaxis correcta =             `$connection =  "mysql:host=". $this->host .";dbname=". $this->db.";user=". $this->user. ";password=" . $this->password;`

Comment: @josanangel que error te da?

Comment: Me dan 2 errores. **El pimero** : `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)' in C:\wamp64\www\CURSOS\CURSO_PHP_7\includes\db.php on line 27` **El segundo:**                               `PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\wamp64\www\CURSOS\CURSO_PHP_7\includes\db.php on line 27`

Comment: Asumo por lo que dice que tu gestor de bases de datos no requiere contraseña, ya probaste pasándole comillas vacías así “” ?

Comment: Correcto ! eso era:  tenia en mi propiedad `contraseña = 'root'` y  realmente no tenia. Mil gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Actualmente PHP usas dos API para gestionar la conexión a la base de datos: `PDO` y `mysqli`. Estas APIs en realidad son clases como cualquier otra y ambas fueron creadas como alternativa a la antigua API `mysql_`,  la cual ya no se debe usar porque ha quedado obsoleta.

En el caso que nos ocupa estamos hablando de PDO, si observas el Manual de PHP verás en efecto que [PDO es una clase](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.pdo.php), con un [constructor](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.construct.php) que recibe unos parámetros bien definidos. Por eso en tu código se usa `new PDO (parametros)`. Al hacer eso simplemente se crea una instancia de la clase PDO, la cual puedes usar para gestionar todo lo relativo a la base de datos mediante los diferentes métodos o propiedades de que dispone la clase.

Veamos los parámetros que acepta el constructor de PDO:

```
public PDO::__construct ( string $dsn [, string $username [, string $password [, array $options ]]] )
```

- **`$dsn`**: cadena con el Nombre del Origen de Datos (DSN), contiene la información requerida para conectarse a la base de datos.
- **`$username`**: cadena con el nombre de usuario para el string del DSN. Este parámetro es opcional para algunos controladores de PDO.
- **`$password`**: cadena con la contraseña para el string del DSN. Este parámetro es opcional para algunos controladores de PDO.
- **`$options`**:  array de la forma clave=>valor con opciones de conexión específicas del controlador. Esas opciones también se pueden establecer aparte mediante el método [`setAttribute()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.setattribute.php). Pero conviene usar ese método solamente si quieres cambiar una configuración de forma dinámica por algún motivo determinado. Las opciones fijas de tu objeto es mejor establecerlas al momento de crearlo, pasándole un array `$options` al constructor, como de hecho ocurre en tu código.

Los parámetros son pasados en ese orden, y si todo marcha bien, la variable a la que se asigne el resultado de `new` será una instancia de la clase PDO. Es por eso por lo que tu código retorna a `$pdo` y no a `$connection`, pues esta última es solamente una cadena.

Recomendaría que apliques aquí el principio de *convención de nombres* para evitar confusiones. En ese sentido, en vez de llamar a tu variable `$connection` sería mejor llamarla `$dsn`, que es lo que representa realmente.

Otra cosa que quiero señalar es que los parámetros que se pasan en `$options` no son banales. Es preciso establecer a `FALSE` las preparaciones emuladas, porque vienen en estado `TRUE` por defecto y en ciertos escenarios se puede emular una consulta preparada con termina en un ataque de *Inyección SQL*.

Estableces un manejo de errores adecuado también es importante, porque si no PDO podría terminar imprimiendo en el log de errores la contraseña y el nombre de usuario cuando hay algún fallo en la conexión. Aparte de manejar adecuadamente los errores, recomiendo que uses contraseñas largas, así al menos las mismas aparecerán truncadas en el error log, en caso de que lleguen a imprimirse (los log de errores son de los archivos favoritos de los hackers para explotar nuestros sistemas).

Otra cosa que quiero señalar es que, si no quieres tener problemas de codificación, conviene que pases en el DSN un parámetro `charset`, de modo que la conexión traiga los datos bien codificados de la base de datos, de lo contrario, cuando haya palabras acentuadas por ejemplo puede que vengan distorsionadas. Al final de `$dsn` agregaremos esto: `;charset=UTF8` y te aseguro que te ahorrará muchos dolores de cabeza :-)

Propongo entonces que escribas el código de este modo:

function connect(){
        try {

```
        $dsn =  "mysql:host=". $this->host .";dbname=". $this->db.";charset=UTF8"; 
        $options = [
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE     => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE,
        ];

        $pdo = new PDO($dsn,$this->user,$this->password,$options);

        return $pdo;

    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        //throw $th;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta como siempre +1

Comment: Gracias @anonimo, tu respuesta también es buena, pero quise contar un poco el sentido de PDO y referir algunas fuentes para que se entienda el por qué de PDO. Saludos.

Comment: De acuerdo, muchas gracias por las aclaraciones.